# command to retrieve which processes are launched at boot time in linux

Tags: sync

I am working on a sync server. I'd like to retrieve which processes are launched at boot time. I have tried `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service`

Answer (score 1):

Use `journalctl`. Read `man journalctl`.

Start with:

```
sudo journalctl -b 0
```

Which shows the current boot's logs.

Answer (score 0):

In order to list out all services at boot time along with their corresponding statuses try below:

```
systemctl -at service
```